# Eval vs execscript

Tags: javascript, eval

Practically every javascript guide on the web shouts to me that eval is bad, don't use it, it's a security hole and whatnot. Recently I discovered window.execScript, which seems to do the same thing as eval. Is one better than the other in terms of security or speed?

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741364(v=vs.85).aspx "IHTMLWindow2::execScript is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use eval".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`window.execScript` is not crossing browsers, only IE supports it.

Comment: Is it exactly the same thing?

Comment: @Delta Check this article http://ajaxian.com/archives/evaling-with-ies-windowexecscript

Comment: This page suggests works in Chrome http://help.dottoro.com/ljoswolk.php

Answer (score 6):

`eval` is bad but it can be replaced with `new Function` most of time, it's safer and it's crossbrowser:

```
var foo = new Function('return 1 + 2');
var baz = eval('function(){ return 1 + 2 }');
```

The main difference is scope access. `eval` can affect local variables where `new Function` creates another scope.

Comment: should be var foo = new Function('return 1 + 2')();     you missed () in the end

Comment: Running the `baz` line from Chrome's debug console gives me a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("

Comment: You code for `baz` doesn't work. You need to wrap that `function(){...}` in `()` to make it a valid function expression or it won't run: `const baz = eval('(function(){return 1 + 2;})');`

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2019.**

Eval is not bad, eval is misunderstood, and is really powerful. Pretty much is what power our developers tools. the Function constructor serves the same purpose of eval and even has the same security vulnerabilities

> The Function constructor creates a new Function object. Calling the
> constructor directly can create functions dynamically, but suffers
> from security and similar (but far less significant) performance
> issues to eval. However, unlike eval, the Function constructor creates
> functions which execute in the global scope only.
> Blockquote
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

There are legit cases for eval and Function which only real difference is how the scope is handle.

I suggest reading these two posts to increase understanding about this topic https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/11/01/eval-is-evil-part-one/
https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Bonus:
if you want to have `new Function` or `Function` to behave the same you can simply do use of indirect eval by typing `(0, eval)`
http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

So there you go, eval and Function pretty much are the same.

Ps. `execScript` has been deprecated.

**Update 2021**

If you are researching eval and you are intending to do a sandbox, make yourself a favor and use something like https://codesandbox.io/post/sandpack-announcement `sandpack` which has solved most of the problem when implementing a sandbox for javascript.